# How to position a command-line console by default on a second TFT-screen?

Tags: python, windows-10

After performing some excavation while using the words "python, execute, script, on second, TFT-screen"  I gave up searching for an answer.

My question - what would I need to do if I want to run "my_imaginary_example_script.py" by default in its own position on a second TFT screen instead of blund on the main TFT-screen?

In my case the py-file contains a socket_server script without GUI. When run it looks like DOS-box type but without shell functions.

Comment: That would be very dependant on the underlying OS and what do you mean under '_run "my_imaginary_example_script.py"_'...

Comment: Adjusted to tag to display the windows10 OS. Added script function in the question.

Comment: You'll need a third-party utility to launch your command on a specific position, check for example [cmdow](https://github.com/ritchielawrence/cmdow) especially it's `/MOV` option.

Comment: Cheers, looks easy in use according to the screenshots provided. Seems to be working for win7.. So I guess its installing under win7 mode if it fails under win10. Tomorrow an update if it did the trick.

Comment: seems incompatible with win10..even if I set it to XP SP2 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(windows10)

Based on [**zwer**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7553525/zwer) his comment I tried and failed with `cmdow` but could search with additional words like (cmdow, console, etc.) and found a very nice comment on superusers [here](https://superuser.com/a/1171501/817765) from [Robert](https://superuser.com/users/690007/robert-m).

Solution for permanent replacement of server console (conhost.exe):

1 - press `Alt` + `SHIFT` and;

2 - go to **"properties"**;

3 - select tab **"layout"**;

4 - go to groupbox **"window selection"**;

5 - uncheck the box **"let system set position"**

**Voila...** next time this console is started its on the new position.

*In addition: window size and hscreen buffer can also be addressed there. No apparent need to use `cmdow` anymore.* Above all...  on windows10  `Ctrl-C` no longer works as exit/quite for this type of server console. Use `Alt` + `F4` instead.