# Window Title not scaling PyQt5 on per monitor DPI

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am running Windows 10 and using PyQt5 (Python 3.6, Qt5.6 from anaconda).  I have two monitors, one HD scaled at 100% and the other a 4K monitor scaled at 150%.  I have a simple GUI example shown below.  Everything scales except the title bar.  Wondering how I can fix that.  See the image below of the two resolutions.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.setWindowTitle("Hello World")
fileMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu("File", window)
longMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu("Long Menu Title", window)
window.menuBar().addMenu(fileMenu)
window.menuBar().addMenu(longMenu)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

Response to an answer below:

setting the window.font() property as per an answer below changes the menu fonts but does not affect the window title bar font.  The following code produces the results in the image below:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.setWindowTitle("Hello World")
fileMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu("File", window)
longMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu("Long Menu Title", window)
window.menuBar().addMenu(fileMenu)
window.menuBar().addMenu(longMenu)
font = window.font()
font.setPointSize(12)
window.setFont(font)     # set font here
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Should be done with `font.setPointSize(x)` where x = 12 as shown in your code below. See also inline comments.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.setWindowTitle("Hello World")

fileMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu("File", window)
longMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu("Long Menu Title", window)
window.menuBar().addMenu(fileMenu)
window.menuBar().addMenu(longMenu)

font = window.font()
font.setPointSize(12)
window.setFont(font)     # set font here
window.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 200)) # gives flexible window size with minimum size.
#window.resize(400, 200)  # fixed size: in case you're using fontsize 26 or so ;-)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think it's best to change `font = QtGui.QFont()` to `font = window.font()` to not change the family.

Comment: modified as suggested :-)

Comment: `window.QFont()` is different to  `window.font()`

Comment: thanks, I will test tomorrow morning when I am back in front of these two monitors

Comment: np... btw.. if you want to pin the window to a particular position on lets say..your second or third screen then the following link helps accomplishing that [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783409/how-to-position-a-socket-server-console-during-a-python-script-run-on-a-second-t].

Comment: @ZF007, unfortunately your suggestion changes the font sizes of the internal window components but does not change the window title bar

Comment: you want to change the "hello world" in size?

Comment: Yes, if you'll note I said in the question that everything scales except the title bar. Everything should scale when changing to a screen with a different pixel density but the window title bar does not